# Google maps v3 - Add markers at the center of tiles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function initialize() {     
var myLatlng;    
var mapOptions;
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.98439980, -95.34140015);

    mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      drawRectangle(map);
      var result = {"regionList":[{"centerLongitude":-95.34890747070312,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.980682373046875},{"centerLongitude":-95.34890747070312,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.988117218017578},{"centerLongitude":-95.33389282226562,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.980682373046875},{"centerLongitude":-95.33389282226562,"imageIcon":"../images/untested-icon.png","centerLatitude":29.988117218017578}]};
      alert(result);
      addMarkersAtRegionCenter(map, result);

    });

function addMarkersAtRegionCenter(map, result) {

    var length = result.regionList.length;
    var regionUrl = "drilledDownToRegion.jsp?";

     for(var i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
            var image = result.regionList[i].imageIcon;
      //alert("Latitude : " + result.regionList[i].centerLatitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.regionList[i].centerLatitude,result.regionList[i].centerLongitude),
            icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
                  map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function() {
                    window.location.href = marker.url;
               }
             })(marker, i));
     }
 }
    function drawRectangle(map) {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();
      var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
      var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

      var numberOfParts = 4;

      var tileWidth = (northEast.lng() - southWest.lng()) / numberOfParts;
      var tileHeight = (northEast.lat() - southWest.lat()) / numberOfParts;
      for (var x = 0; x < numberOfParts; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < numberOfParts; y++) {
          var areaBounds = {
            north: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * (y+1)),
            south: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),
            east: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * (x+1)),
            west: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x)
          };

          var area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            //strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            //fillColor: '#FF0000',
            //fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            bounds: areaBounds

          });

        }
      }
    }   
  }   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

In the above code, I am trying to add markers at the center of each rectangle. But I am not able to add markers. I have hard coded image icon value since I don't have image mentioned in the array.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't simply show the icon ... in your json? check if the path is correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related question: [Google maps api v3 - divide region into equal parts using tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675769/google-maps-api-v3-divide-region-into-equal-parts-using-tiles)

Simpler to add the markers to the centers of the rectangles when you create them:

```
var centerMark = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: area.getBounds().getCenter(),
  map: map
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lnn54cqg/1/)

To add the markers from the response to the map (the positions in the posted response are not at the center of the squares), this is the same function you posted in your question, [it works for me (the blue markers), I modified your click listener to open an infowindow (rather than do a redirect of the page)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lnn54cqg/4/):

```
function addMarkersAtRegionCenter(map, result) {
  var length = result.regionList.length;
  var regionUrl = "drilledDownToRegion.jsp?";
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var image = result.regionList[i].imageIcon;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.regionList[i].centerLatitude, result.regionList[i].centerLongitude),
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png',
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        // window.location.href = marker.url;
        infowindow.setContent("regionList:" + i + "<br>centLat=" + result.regionList[i].centerLatitude + "<br>centLng=" + result.regionList[i].centerLongitude + "<br>imageIcon=" + result.regionList[i].imageIcon + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted add markers using result array which contains image and latitude and longitude of each tile center. I am getting the result from the database. I have to decide the image icon for each tile based on some business logic. Can you please try to show the center and marker using the result array? You can use some other icon as proof of concept in the json which can be shown on the map. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you are trying to do.  How is the results array getting the center coordinates? If you are sending the center coordinates to the server, then you should just be able to create the markers when the callback runs.

Comment: The posted code works for me to display the markers provided in the posted "results" see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lnn54cqg/4/)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hi geocodezip, If i click on one of the markers on the divided rectangular region, how can i show the clicked rectangle portion for the entire view port? I have tried using the following code but i had to increase zoom to 16. Is it possible to show that rectangular region in the full map without increasing zoom?

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      bounds.extend(32.89131546020508,-97.05835723876953);
      bounds.extend(32.90044403076172,-97.02222442626953);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);