# Google maps - divide region into equal parts and show ONLY clicked region on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code sample to divide map into equal regions. When clicking on marker at the center of a rectangle then how can i show only that particular rectangle region on google map? All other regions should NOT be in the map after clicking on marker.

```
function initialize() {     
var myLatlng;    
var mapOptions;

myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.98439980, -95.34140015);

    mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      drawRectangle(map);
    });

    function drawRectangle(map) {
      var bounds = map.getBounds();
      var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
      var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

      var numberOfParts = 4;

      var tileWidth = (northEast.lng() - southWest.lng()) / numberOfParts;
      var tileHeight = (northEast.lat() - southWest.lat()) / numberOfParts;
      for (var x = 0; x < numberOfParts; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < numberOfParts; y++) {
          var areaBounds = {
            north: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * (y+1)),
            south: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),
            east: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * (x+1)),
            west: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x)
          };

          var area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            //strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            //fillColor: '#FF0000',
            //fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            bounds: areaBounds
          });
          var centerMark = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: area.getBounds().getCenter(),
          map: map,
          title: area.getBounds().getCenter().toUrlValue(6)
          });
        }
      }
    }   
  }   

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

I have tried using the map bounds code but it is not working as expected. it works only if i increase the zoom. But zoom may be different for each region.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(southLatitude, eastLongitude);
    bounds.extend(northLatitude, westLongitude);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Previous/related question: [Google maps v3 - Add markers at the center of tiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746030/google-maps-v3-add-markers-at-the-center-of-tiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the bounds of each rectangle as a property of the center marker, then use `map.fitBounds` to center and zoom the map to the rectangular area:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(centerMark, 'click', function(evt) {
  // center and zoom the map to completely show the area
  map.fitBounds(this.area);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    // increase the zoom by one level to remove the padding.
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
  })
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnn54cqg/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng;
  var mapOptions;

  myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.98439980, -95.34140015);

  mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    drawRectangle(map);
  });

  function drawRectangle(map) {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();

    var numberOfParts = 4;

    var tileWidth = (northEast.lng() - southWest.lng()) / numberOfParts;
    var tileHeight = (northEast.lat() - southWest.lat()) / numberOfParts;
    for (var x = 0; x < numberOfParts; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < numberOfParts; y++) {
        var areaBounds = {
          north: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * (y + 1)),
          south: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),
          east: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * (x + 1)),
          west: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x)
        };

        var area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          //strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          //fillColor: '#FF0000',
          //fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: areaBounds
        });
        var centerMark = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: area.getBounds().getCenter(),
          map: map,
          area: areaBounds,
          title: area.getBounds().getCenter().toUrlValue(6)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(centerMark, 'click', function(evt) {
          map.fitBounds(this.area);
          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
          });

        });
      }
    }
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: It works if you are showing the clicked rectangular region on the same page. But if i want to show the clicked region on a new page, i can't pass area as a parameter to the next page. Is there any way to do this on a new web apge?

Comment: That is a different/new question.